What determines the hash in My.Settings folder name?
My My.Settings are saved in
%localappdata%/<MyCompanyName>/<exename>.exe_Url_<hash>/<version_number>/user.config
which is fine, but I want to ensure <hash> doesn't change between versions. What do I need to not change to do that?
The reason I want to know is because updates to my application call My.Settings.Upgrade() to import settings from the previous installed version. If this part of the path changes, the upgrade won't work and the user loses their settings. One example of where this happens if you turn strong-naming on or off.

The following may be of interest: Publish ClickOnce applications and Access local and remote data in ClickOnce applications

Those links don't seem to contain that information. Also, I'm not using ClickOnce so it doesn't behave that way - eg. copying old version's files to new version.

Please provide a minimal, reproducible example which others can use to re-create the issue that you're facing. Unfortunately, the information you've provided is insufficient.

I'm not having an issue. I want to anticipate what will this cause this issue before it happens. I've added a clarifying paragraph now.

One factor is the path to the .exe file. I renamed its parent folder and that caused it to create a new settings file with a new hash in its path.
